# How to get full file path (image file) using AngularJs

Tags: .net, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to get the full file name using directive with angularjs , 
Bellow is my code, here I am only getting file name. Is it possible to get the full file name?

`<input type="file" fileread="justice.imageLocation" />`

`MyApp.directive('fileread', [function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread:"="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        // I am getting file name here!
                        scope.fileread = changeEvent.target.files[0].name; 
                    });
            });
        }
    }
}]);`

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a javascript/html question and has nothing to do with angular.

However it is simply not possible to get the path of a file client side, see this question for more information:

[How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post but if someone is trying to do this in node webkit, just change .name to .path so it looks like this: `changeEvent.target.files[0].path;`
That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#tryy').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#tryyyy").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

Comment: When you gives an answer, please add some information and also what is the actual problem with OP's code.